# Desktop Ubuntu 12.04 fails to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I'm using a Samsung ultrabook. I used the windows installer to install Ubuntu 12.04. When I restart PC I get an option to choose which boot to use. If I choose Windows 8 - everything is fine. No problems with Windows 8. If I choose Ubuntu the boot fails. There is this information on the black screen:

```
\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
Status: 0xc000007b
required file contains errors
```

I'm not sure what is wrong or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Boot entry is corrupted.
Use a BCD boot manipulation tool for creating a new entry.
I suggest [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). You can download a free version.
Create a new boot entry and check it multiple time for working correctly.
If it works, remove previous old bad boot entry.
Please note that required boot files is located on root of your boot partition.

**UPDATE:**
After little joojling (googling ;) ) i found this very helpful link [about restoring Wubi boot entry using EasyBCD and some CMD command.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/)

Good luck!

Comment: No, EasyBCD would not help because it cannot create an entry for Wubi.

Comment: See updated paragraph